# BJT PNP and Zener diode circuit analysis problem

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, zener

I am facing a problem in solving a mixed circuit with a PNP BJT and a Zener diode.

I solved the problem but my results are different from the solution.

Could you tell me if my procedure is correct? I don’t understand the difference, especially in R1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you were given a bad question and you gave us no textbook answer

Comment: your answer looks correct and author made 2 mistakes. a) PNP and b) called Vie = 2.5mA  (= Ie perhaps). What answer were  you given?

Comment: @Tony Actually, that's a valid circuit topology (ignoring specific values for now.) I've seen it used when you want the collector voltage to vary in-phase with a rising Vcc. This can be desired in some power regulator circuits I don't see often, but have seen used in the past and for good reason when I saw them. (A floating difference value, for example.)

Comment: It may be valid for obscure applications with push currents to + rail but this is a classic negative voltage regulator . with 20V = gnd.

Comment: Sorry ,I forgot  include the answers of the exercise to compare with my results.

Comment: @Tony I think I know one of the places I've seen it used to good effect. (Not this exact circuit, but one relying upon a similar concept.) If I can find it, again, this will confirm my poor memory and I may post it up as the conclusion of a short answer.

Comment: Did you get similar answer to OP? For R Values

Comment: @Tony I haven't even tried. I'm far more curious to recover the location of the power supply textbook I'm looking for. It contained an interesting use, like this topology. But my library of 5000 books here is... big... and I'm not a librarian.

Comment: @JeanPool I get \$R_1\approx 560\:\Omega\$ and \$V_{\text{B}}\approx 12.3\:\text{V}\$ from KCL at the base by solving the following two equations, simultaneously:$$\begin{align*}\frac{V_\text{B}}{R_1}+\frac{V_\text{B}}{R_\text{Z}=22\:\Omega}&=\left(I_\text{B}=25\:\mu\text{A}\right)+\frac{V_\text{CC}=20\:\text{V}}{R_1}+\frac{V_\text{Z}=12\:\text{V}}{R_\text{Z}=22\:\Omega}\\\\R_1&=\frac{\left(V_\text{CC}=20\:\text{V}\right)-V_\text{B}}{I_{R_1}=13.75\:\text{mA}}\end{align*}$$Therefore, \$R_2=2.8\:\text{k}\Omega\$. Please do note the value \$R_\text{Z}=22\:\Omega\$. It's not there for grins.

Comment: I would propose a few clarifications about your question. 1) "I don’t know the difference especially in the r1." That sentence doesn't make much sense in my English.  Since I am native French , that may be my own interpretation, but still, I do not comprehend what you want to say here.  2) Rz=22, I assume 22ohms. It would be better to have mentioned it. 3) Vie=2.5mA - that is not a voltage it is current, hence Ie=2.5mA would have been better. 4) "What happen if the value in R3 goes up?" Not a clear question. I assumed you meant "What happen to the voltage on R3 if the value of R3 goes up"

Comment: @jonk -- Very nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It would appear that your solutions for R2 and R3 are incorrect.
R2 must equal to 2.8k and R3 must equal to 3.6k
I thoroughly checked my calculations and I doubt any mistake. Please correct me if otherwise.
One mistake in your analysis is that you neglected to take into consideration the lost of voltage in the Zener internal resistor of 22 ohms, which is not neglectable, 300mV, which must be added to the the Zener voltage, hence total voltage on the Base would become 12.3V
Proof could be seen in the correct computation of R1 = 559.78ohms = 560ohms
The rest is simple math. Determining Ve you find R2 which must equal 2799ohms otherwise your Vb or VZ become something different from factual values.
One must assume that your two values R2 and R3, then, are erroneous.
I recalculated backward using your proposed values for R2 and R3 and it is impossible to make any sense if some other factual values such as Vz(12) or Ir1 or Rz(22) or Vec(4) are not modified.
It would be possible to adjust those values such that R2 and R3 become valid but then R1 would not match.

Answer (score -1):

- Normally all +VE regulators use NPN not PNP.
- Modern LDO's use Pch FET's where the load is to ground ( = 0V, by definition) .

So your question (or teacher's question) is unusual, because no external LOAD is defined and wrong conventional polarity is used.

But **Vec** is defined and that with **Ic** is the driving factor for R2,R3.

- **Assuming** Zener voltage is rated at current given (not likely but close enuf.)

  - Vz= Vt+ Iz*Rz = 12.0V @ 25'C & Vt is not given here yet found in datasheets.
  - so we assert;
  - Vz = 12.0V , Ve = 12.0 +0.7 = 12.7, thus drop 4V , **Vc = 8.8 V**
  - **Vie= 2.5mA ??** no Ie=2.5mA , **Re=2.92k** = Ve/Ie= (20-12.7)/2.5mA
  - **Rc = 3.56k** = Vc/Ic=8.8/(2.5*0.99) ,  Ic=0.99*Ie (hFE=99)

looks to be same as your answer.  **bad question? or given wrong answer**

(clever name Jean) Gene